# Clustering jbi end points on Servicemix 4.5.3

Tags: jms, apache-servicemix, jbi

I am using Servicemix 4.5.3 and I have the consumer endpoint deployed on (HTTP BC) on Instance 1 and I have the provider endpoint deployed on (HTTP BC) on instance 2 with both instances interconnected by network of brokers.

When I invoke the consumer end point I get the below error:
`org.apache.servicemix.nmr.api.ServiceMixException`: Could not dispatch exchange. No matching endpoints.

This is fine as I have not enabled clustering for provider and consumer end points.

I am following this link for enabling the clustering of the end points
http://fusesource.com/docs/esb/4.2/jbi/ESBJBICluster.html

I have two questions:
1) If I enable clustering of both the end points will the target end point ( ie the provider end point) now be resolved ?

2) I get the below error when I try to deploy the consumer Service unit on Instance 1. Is there any thing wrong in my xbean configuration?
 Does any one know what is the cause of this error?

Thank you,
Arun

PS:
This is my xbean.xml inside the consumer SU.

```
<http:soap-consumer service="tx:httpSoapConsumer"
        endpoint="TaxiProviderHttpSoapConsumerEndpoint" 
        locationURI="http://localhost:8163/httpSoapConsumer/TaxiProviderHttpSoapConsumerEndpoint"
        targetService="tx:httpSoapProvider"
        targetEndpoint="httpSoapProviderEndpoint" wsdl="classpath:service.wsdl"
        useJbiWrapper="false"
        />

    <bean class="org.apache.servicemix.jbi.cluster.engine.OsgiSimpleClusterRegistration">
        <property name="name" value="c1" />
        <property name="serviceName" value="tx:httpSoapConsumer" />
        <property name="endpointName" value="TaxiProviderHttpSoapConsumerEndpoint" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

ERROR:

```
`<stack-trace><![CDATA[org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.apache.servicemix.jbi.cluster.engine.OsgiSimpleClusterRegistration#0' defined in file [/home/ubuntu/ProductionEnvironment/MultiInstanceESB/Test1/data/jbi/aruntest.http.Consumer.endpoint.sa/sus/aruntest.http.consumer.endpoint/xbean.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.servicemix.jbi.cluster.engine.OsgiSimpleClusterRegistration.afterPropertiesSet(OsgiSimpleClusterRegistration.java:43)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethod

This is the line causing the Exception: (OsgiSimpleClusterRegistration.java:43)
serviceRegistration = bundleContext.registerService(ClusterRegistration.class.getName(), this, new Properties());
```

Comment: JBI is deprecated - I would suggest not to use JBI if you are developing new projects with ServiceMix.

Comment: Hi Claus, But this is already existing project developed using JBI and to enable clustering this was the technique I found online. Do you suggest any other methods ?